# Writing kernel driver aio_read, aio_write support

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers

I'm currently about to write aio support for a kernel module I wrote for communication with a fast device (125 MB/s) in an embedded environment. To get started, I wanted to look at a few examples on how to approach this, so I ran `grep -ri aio_write .` in a 3.13 kernel.

However, upon further inspection, I noticed that *most* if not *all* fs drivers actually perform `aio_write` and `aio_read` synchronously. At most, they make use of vectored inputs to save on buffer allocation.

The only driver I was able to find, which actually supports asynchronous aio, is the gadget USB driver, `drivers/usb/gadget/inode.c`

1. Does this observation mean I'm likely *not* to benefit from writing my own aio routines?
2. Are `libaio`, `librt` considered *good enough* for my target bandwidth?
3. Is this feature *too new* or *very controversial* and likely to be gone in a few kernels' time?

I already noticed that pinning multiple user pages and DMA'ing them out to my peripheral is actually **slower** than just `copy_from_user` them to a `PAGE_SIZE` `kmalloc`'d buffer and loop a few times.

I fear that I might be putting a lot of time and effort into aio when it would actually end up slower than my simplistic `read`/`write` approach of copying user buffers over and DMA'ing them out synchronously and blocking until the DMA is done.

I'd be grateful for some experienced users' insights into this to help me evaluate aio.